# iOS: How to make a CPTTradingRangePlot .stickLength be dynamic?

Tags: core-plot

> How to set the **CPTTradingRangePlot** **stickLength** dynamically in
>   core plot iOS?

```
CPTTradingRangePlot *tradePlot = [(CPTTradingRangePlot *)[CPTTradingRangePlot alloc] initWithFrame :....];
tradePlot.barWidth    =  5.0;
tradePlot.stickLength = 10.0f;                   //can i vary this dynamically
```

[Graph ScreenShot Link](http://1drv.ms/1EJCA6p)

The length of the symbol or (CPTTradingRangePlot) sticklength varies not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `stickLength` or any other Core Plot property at any time, as long as you call the setter from the main thread. The `stickLength` and [many other properties](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/group__animation.html) are animatable using Core Animation or [`CPTAnimation`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_animation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.I wanted to create a plot [Graph Link](http://1drv.ms/1EJCA6p) is it possible in core plot